# Error while calling sort on a list of quickfix items even though the list items are copied to a local variable

Tags: vim

Below error is observed while calling `TestQFItem` even though list items are copied to a local variable using `let itemsCopied = deepcopy(items)`:

```
Error detected while processing function TestQFItem:  
line: 3  
E:21 cannot make changes, modifiable is off:^Isort(itemscopied,function("CompareQuickFixItems"))
```

**Even though the list items are copied to a local variable using deepcopy why vim is throwing the error "E:21 cannot make changes, modifiable is off"?**

```
function! CompareQuickFixItems(arg1, arg2)
  if a:arg1['lnum'] == a:arg2['lnum']
    return 0
  elseif a:arg1['lnum'] < a:arg2['lnum']
    return -1
  else
    return 1
  endif
endfunction


function! TestQFItem()
    let items = getqflist()
    let itemsCopied = deepcopy(items)
    call sort(itemsCopied, function("CompareQuickFixItems"))
    call setqflist(itemsCopied, "r")
endfunction
```

Comment: `modifiable` is about buffers, not variables -- you don't need to copy the `items` list.Have you done something special to qf-buffer? (I've never add any trouble to execute `setqflist()` on a new list -- I don't use `'r'` either)

Comment: I am adding few lines from a txt file in a random order to the quick fix list & then sort the quickfix list according to the lines numbers.

Comment: Hum... You means this is not your real code? Could it be that you have forgotten to `:call`  the `sort()`  function?